# Model and ViewModel binding with View

Tags: wpf, mvvm

**Scenario:**

1. I have CustomerOrder View Model
2. It contains One Drop Down List (For Customer) and Multiple Text Boxes (For Order Details)
3. In View Model, Customer Drop Down List is bound to variable CustomerList of type Customer Model object(Id, Name)
4. Selected Customer of drop down list is bound to Customer model object
5. Customer Model implements IDataErrorInfo through BaseModel

**My Problem:** 
1. Now, in ViewModel, to track if Combobox contains valid Customer, i need to implement IDataErrorInfo in View Model

1. My Model also implements IDataErrorInfo through BaseModel

**Question:**

1. I don't want to write IDataErrorInfo at 2 places. Can you please suggest on it?

Answer (score 0):

i would say - if you bind to your viewmodel properties and want validation you have to implement IDataErrorInfo there. what you can do is to "delegate" the validation to your model.

//viewmodel

```
    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get 
        {
            //todo: other validationlogic which is not in the model

            return this._mymodel[columnName];
        }
    }
```